# Get 12 hours before and after current time

Tags: java, time, java-time

I'm having an issue working with time in Java. I don't really understand how to efficiently solve comparing the time of **now** and **12 hours before and after**

I get a set of starting times for a show from an API and then compare that starting time with `LocalTime.now()`. It looks something like this:

```java
SimpleDateFormat sdt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String temp = sdt.format(Local.time(now));
LocalTime secondTime = LocalTime.parse(parts1[0]);
LocalTime firstTime = LocalTime.parse(temp);
int diff = (int) ((MINUTES.between(firstDay, secondDay) + 1440) % 1440);
if(diff <= 720){
    return true;
}
```

Where my idea is that if the difference between the two times is smaller than 720 minutes (12 hours) I should get the correct output. And this works for the 12 hours before now. I thought I might need to swap the parameters of `.between`, to get the other side of the day. That counts it completely wrong (If the time now is 15:00:00 it would accept all the times until 22:00:00 the same day). Is this just a really bad way of comparing two times? Or is it just my math that lacks understanding of what I'm trying to do?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just take the starting date and add/subtract 12 hours from that to get the range you want to compare the current time with?

Comment: Are you not allowed to use `LocalTime#minusHours`?

Comment: @Thomas Did not know you could do that, will defiantly try, Thanks!

Comment: @daniu Again did not know that existed, will try if i can't get Thomas answer to work. Thanks

Comment: You should use class [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) rather than class `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Well, actually what daniu mentioned is what I meant as well. Just use the appropriate methods to add and subtract the hours.

Comment: I am sorry, there is no way that I can understand what you want. Two times are *always* within 12 hours of each other, one way or the other (if the times are 03:00 and 22:00, there are only 5 hours from 22:00 till 03:00 the next day, for example). I have voted to close needing clarity.

Comment: @OleV.V i'm sorry. The problem i was having was that i got a start time and a date for a show from a API. I wanted to see if that time and date occurred in between 12 hours from now and after now. A more clear question might have been how to know if a time and date is in between a 24 hour interval? Hope that gives more clarity to my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the 'new' (not that new) Java 8 time API:

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
Instant hoursAfter = now.plus(12, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
Instant hoursBefore = now.minus(12, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
```

Comment: Can i use something similar like between when using Instant? I need to see if a time lies in between those instants

Comment: Use two calls to `Instant.isAfter` and `Instant.isBefore` with the appropriate logic. If you're on an earlier API version, you will probably have to use `compareTo`

Comment: Thank you, what i was looking for!

Comment: @forsb Note that 'Instant' means that 12*60*60 seconds are subtracted/added. This means that you may find that '2 o'clock + 12 hours' turns into '3 o'clock at night'. Daylight savings and all that. If you want to turn 2 o'clock afternoon into 2 o'clock at night, even if that means only 11 or 13 hours later due to DST switches, use e.g. LocalDateTime and `.addHours(12)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

First, doing this kind of operations on `java.time.LocalTime` won't work! Or at least only if the time is "12:00:00" …

That is because you will have an over-/underflow when you add/substract 12 hours from any other time.

So your starting point should be to go for `java.time.LocalDateTime` (at least, although I would go for `java.time.Instant`). Now you can handle the over-/underflow, as you will get another day when adding or subtracting 12 hours.

How this works is shown in [this anwswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65630928/1554195): `LocalDateTime` allows nearly the same operations as `Instant`.